# How to handle null in list<> when using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I found this very handy little piece of code to build a list of comma separated values using the property of a given class stored in a list (Just google ToComma link - article is on codeproject).

I've modified it to handle a specific separator and it works great, but sometimes, some of the properties for a given object will contain a null value and I'm wondering if it is possible to expand this code to handle the null and replace it by a default value based on the property type i.e. if string, replace null by string.empty, if numeric, replace it by 0, if bool replace it by false.

If the property in question that I'm trying to build of comma separated value happen to contain a null value, it will throw an error i.e. object reference not set to an instance...

Here is the code:

```
public static string ToSeparator<T, TU>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
Func<T, TU> func, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, source.Select(s => func(s).ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Assuming you have a list i.e. List persons, where the Person object is made up of FirstName, Surname and Age for example, you can then simply call it:

```
persons.ToSeparator(m => m.FirstName, "-"); 
persons.ToSeparator(m => m.Age, "-");
```

Can this be done using the above code? If it can't be done using the above code, what would be the best way to handle this using link and/or lambda expression.

Thanks.

Comment: *"if numeric, replace it by 0, if bool replace it by false."* - That's already done for you considering that you cannot have a `null` in a `List<int>`, `List<bool>`, etc. unless you are using something like `List<object>` and boxing them.

Comment: Hi Ed, that's correct, though I haven't tested this yet. The field that's returning me a null is of type String, so technically, it's the only one that should give me grief, well any nullable types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for *custom* default values here.  The only thing that makes any sense is the `string => ""` conversion as you cannot have a null in a typed collection where T is a value type unless you have something like a `List<object>` and are boxing them.

Since `default(string)` really is `null` and will be the same for any reference type, you'll need to pass in the default value to the method.  You can use :

```
source.Select(x => {
                  var value = func(x);
                  return value == null ? defaultValue : value.ToString();
              });
```

Comment: Hi Ed, would you mind explaining to me how to create a CustomDefault. It's not just string, main types would be string, numeric, Boolean and date.

Comment: @Thierry: Add a `string defaultValue` argument.  There's no need to do so for value types from what you've shown as they cannot be null.

Comment: @Thierry:  It is a string because it is a part of the output, and your function returns a string.  It is a default *representation* for null values.

Comment: thanks for this! It worked. How do I post the final code? It's slightly different from the one you mentioned? Do I answer my own question do I edit yours?

Comment: @"Ed S.", I've marked your answer as correct but really got to hit the sack, so I'll answer my own question with the code for both function (one without default value and one with default value). The one without the default value will do for me for now, but the trick was to split the code and assign func(x) to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, either,

```
... s=>s==null? "[Undefined]": func(s).ToString() ...
```

or add the where query,

```
.. .Where(s=>s!=null).Select(s=>func(s).ToString()) ...
```

Comment: I know this comment is similar to the one below, but the option of where changes the behavior.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but this does not work with the function I presented above as it is expecting a type TU to be returned, even though it should be a string. As for the where, WhyMe is correct, I cannot use that as it would exclude them while I need to include them but use default instead of null.

Comment: I dont understant the issue, the trinity operator should be fine. Both return string. func(s).ToString should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing the Func that is being passed into your ToSeparator, there is no way you can know what errors may happen in that function.

You could surround your execution of the func in your method with a try/catch block, and return something else when you catch an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
public static string ToSeparator<T, TU>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T, TU> func, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, source.Select(s => (s == null ? default(TU) : func(s))
        .ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Note that in the case where your selector is "deeper" than the property on the parent type, ie:

```
persons.ToSeparator(m => m.Address.ZipCode, "-");
```

This completely falls apart. Best to do the select first, handling the null similarly to how I did (maybe create another extension method for SelectNullOrDefault or something) and then pass THAT as the source to your ToSeparator method... Would be much safer.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but it didn't work. I can see what you're doing and would love to understand it better so I could figure this out like this, and while what you suggested looks like would have worked, it doesn't... Any other suggestions? I've just noticed that default(TU) is null, rather than ""

Comment: He isn't asking for *actual* defaults for a given type, i.e., he wants a null for a string to be represented as an empty string.

Comment: @Ed - Console.WriteLine("\"" + null + "\""); // output ""

Comment: @Thierry: the null will output as empty string when used in string.Join

Comment: Hi David, I still want to use the function above the way you suggested but instead of using default(TU) is there a way to call a function as you suggested where I could check for a value being null and return an appropriate string based on it's type?

Comment: You could build such a function, yes. It would consist of a lot of if blocks I imagine.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the final solution (Thanks @Ed S., everyone!)

```
public static string ToSeparator<T, TU>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
Func<T, TU> func, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, source.Select(x => {
              var value = func(x);
              return value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
          }));
    }
```

and

```
public static string ToSeparator<T, TU, TZ>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
Func<T, TU> func, TZ defaultValue, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, source.Select(x =>
        {
            var value = func(x);
            return value == null ? defaultValue.ToString() : value.ToString();
        }));
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else!!

Comment: Wouldn't the default value be of type TU? Shouldn't need that TZ parameter imho

Comment: @Ned Stoyanov, no as using default will return null, even for a string which will cause this to fail and throw an error which is what i wanted to sort out to begin with.